# Cannot static link to glewInit() with Mingw

Tags: hyperlink, mingw, glew

I am currently building a program using GLEW, compiled with MinGW ( in Eclipse ).  I built the GLEW libs from the source provided by the GLEW website.

I have been able to use the GLEW declared functions without a problem if I link with the .DLL.  However, if I try to link with the static library ( libglew32.a ) with the "GLEW_STATIC" flag defined, I get an error for the function "glewInit()":

undefined reference to `*imp*_glewInit@0'

If I open up libglew32.a in a hex editor, I can see that there is an entry, but it is named _glewInit@0.  So it seems like the disconnect is that my program's compile is trying to append this "*imp*" string to the front of the function name in the library.

It seems like there must be mis-match of the calling convention here, but I don't know what would cause it yet.  There are certainly lots of different ways that GLEW declares the api functions in the header depending on what compiler definitions are set, but I haven't narrowed it down yet.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that *imp* prefix gets added for function stubs that are intended to be loaded at runtime from a .DLL.  In other words, I wasn't actually staticly linking against GLEW.  It turned out that I didn't quite have my eclipse C++ symbols set up correctly, so GLEW_STATIC was not being defined.  After making sure that it was set up in the g++ call, it links just fine.